# How to calculate the gain for a load cell to be used with instrumentation amp?

Tags: gain, instrumentation-amplifier, load-cell

I was hoping someone can give me a step by step process for calculating the gain of my load cell.Here is the datasheet to it [LoadCell datasheet](http://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf/datasheet-3132.pdf). 
I also plan on using the INA125p instrumentation amplifier. 
Here is the datasheet to it <[INA125p Datasheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/56682/BURR-BROWN/INA125P.html)

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The load cell has a stated "gain" of 0.8mV / volt at a mass of 780g. This means that with 1 volt as excitation and 780g placed on the load cell the output voltage will change by 0.8mV. With 10V excitation the output would move by 8mV. Note also that the figure of 0.8mV is subject to a tolerance of +/-0.1mV. There is also an offset (error) voltage that needs to be taken into account.